# Get Array From XML Nodes

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml excerpt:

```
<Names>
<Name lang="en">Soccer</Name>
<Name lang="it">Calcio</Name>
</Names>
```

I would like to get an array like this

```
$names = array(    
   "en" => "Soccer",
   "it" => "Calcio"
)
```

I tried with **simple_load_file()** and then traversing the nodes:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($xmlObject->Names->Name);$i++):
  $output[$xmlObject->Names->Name[$i]['lang'] = $xmlObject->Names->Name[$i];
endfor;
```

but doesnot work.

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement` instances need to be cast to strings

Comment: You were pretty close but just made the little mistake (a common one btw) to think that you would need to specify the root element `Names`, but you don't need to: https://eval.in/204444 - *but doesnot work* is also not a good programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to get an array like the one you want would be to do this:

```
$dom = simplexml_load_file($yourFile);
$result = array();
foreach ($dom as $node)
{//iterate over elements
    if ($node->getName() === 'Name')
    {//make sure to only process Name tags
         $lang = null;
         foreach ($node->attributes() as $name => $val)
         {//find the attribtues
             if ($name == 'lang')
             {//we have the lang attribute
                 $lang = (string) $val;//cast to string!
                 break;//we're done here
             }
         }
         if ($lang)
             $result[$lang] = (string) $node;//cast node to string to get its contents
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

The output will be:

```
array(2) {
  ["en"]=>
  string(6) "Soccer"
  ["it"]=>
  string(6) "Calcio"
}
```

## [demo here](https://eval.in/202559)

As OIS suggested in his answer, you could also use `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`, which allows you to do away with those ugly nested loops. Apart from the XPath he suggested, I'd probably go for that approach:

```
foreach ($dom->xpath('//Name[@lang]') as $name)
    $result[(string) $name['lang']] = (string) $name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply use xpath since I find that easier. With [@lang] only Name nodes with attribute lang will be selected. Edit: Since that was just an excerpt, I made it //Names so it will also be found if it is not root.

```
$test = <<< EOF
<Names>
<Name lang="en">Soccer</Name>
<Name lang="it">Calcio</Name>
</Names>
EOF;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($test);
$arr = array();
foreach ($xml->xpath("//Names/Name[@lang]") as $node) {
    $arr[(string) $node["lang"]] = (string) $node;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["en"]=>
  string(6) "Soccer"
  ["it"]=>
  string(6) "Calcio"
}
```

Comment: Good idea using xPath, but wouldn't `$xml->xpath('//Name[@lang]')` make more sense here? Anyway +1 for xpath, hope you don't mind my adding it to my answer

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem They are the same as long as it's always just /Names/Name and no other nodes. If there are other nodes and they contain Name then //Name might include too many hits.

Comment: That's exactly why I would use `//Name[@lang]`: aprat from the rather short XML snippet the OP has given us, we don't really know what the actual data looks like. A broad xpath might include too many nodes, but I'd rather have too much data than too little. Ah well, down to the OP to decide

Comment: Then I'd rather use //Names/Name tbh